# How to change the color of a UISearchBar in a UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I have a UISearchBar that is part of a UISearchController, that is on top of a UICollectionViewController. I want to change the background of the UISearchBar so that it's an image of my choosing, and the textfield's background to be translucent. Basically, I want to turn this:

[image: This is what it looks like with the given code]

Into this:

[image: After]

I've tried everything I could find here. I tried searchBar.SetBackgroundImage with every single possible combination of UISearchBarPosition and UIBarMetrics, none of them work. The best I've reached is changing the icon for the search. Which accomplishes nothing for me. I think it's because it's embedded in a UINavigationItem. I have no idea why it's not working. Here is what I have set up.

```
var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let searchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchTable") as! SearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = searchTable

        //Sets up the search bar and adds it to navigation header
        let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Find a Result"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
               searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Horses.jpg"), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)

        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the code:

```
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Horses"), forSearchBarIcon: UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal);

var searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
if searchTextField!.respondsToSelector(Selector("attributedPlaceholder")) {
    var color = UIColor.purpleColor()
    let attributeDict = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purpleColor()]
    searchTextField!.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "search", attributes: attributeDict)
}
```

Comment: Nope. This changes the Icon. I want to change the background image